# Does Grub2 have a way of uniquely labelling the menu entries that can be used to set the default for booting?

Tags: grub2, uuid, defaults

Does `grub2` have a means of selecting a menu entry by a unique label instead of the current numbering system which results in commands like `grub-reboot '1>3'`, `GRUB_DEFAULT="1"`, `GRUB_DEFAULT="1>3"`?

What I have in mind are more line the UUIDs used for selecting partitions to boot from, rather than expressions like (hd0,1), (hd1,1) etc. I would prefer to enter random UUIDs in the menu entries and use GRUB_DEFAULT="MENUID=2XDR" rather than numbered entries which are hard to compute?

Answer (score 2):

Set the exact name from the menuentry as GRUB_DEFAULT, for example `Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-62-generic (upstart)`, see:

```
perl -lne "print \$1 if /menuentry '(.*?)'/" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Debian has a habit of using duplicate names for different installations of the same OS even if they are different versions. I want to use the UUID of the `root` partition for GRUB_DEFAULT as it is bound to be unique.